# Join two queries side by side

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need help in joining the two queries below. I am new to Oracle. I went through the posts here but the joins mentioned are for simple queries. Please help me in displaying the result of below two queries side by side.

```
(select Branch, count(*) as "No of Accounts Opened"
      from (SELECT A.CUST_AC_NO,
                   A.CCY,
                   A.branch_code Branch,
                   A.ACY_CURR_BALANCE,
                   A.AC_OPEN_DATE,
                   B.CUSTOMER_NAME1,
                   C.LIMIT_AMOUNT,
                   D.ACCOUNT_CLASS,
                   D.DESCRIPTION
              FROM STTM_CUST_ACCOUNT  A,
                   STTM_CUSTOMER      B,
                   getm_facility      C,
                   STTM_ACCOUNT_CLASS D,
                   getm_liab_cust     e
             WHERE B.CUSTOMER_NO = A.CUST_NO
               AND A.ACCOUNT_CLASS = D.ACCOUNT_CLASS
               and c.liab_id = e.liab_id
               and e.customer_no = b.customer_no
               and e.customer_no = a.cust_no
               AND B.LIABILITY_NO = e.customer_no
               AND RTRIM(C.LINE_CoDe) || LTRIM(TO_CHAR(C.LINE_SERIAL)) =
                   RTRIM(A.LINE_ID)
               AND A.RECORD_STAT = 'O'
               and c.record_stat = 'O'
               and e.record_stat = 'O'
                  --AND to_char(A.AC_OPEN_DATE,'YYYY')=:Year
                  --AND trim(to_char(A.AC_OPEN_DATE,'Month'))=:Month
                  --AND a.BRANCH_CODE ='001'
               AND A.CCY <> 'ZWD'
            UNION
            SELECT A.CUST_AC_NO,
                   A.CCY,
                   Branch_code Branch,
                   A.ACY_CURR_BALANCE,
                   A.AC_OPEN_DATE,
                   B.CUSTOMER_NAME1,
                   NULL LIMIT_AMOUNT,
                   D.ACCOUNT_CLASS,
                   D.DESCRIPTION
              FROM STTM_CUST_ACCOUNT  A,
                   STTM_CUSTOMER      B,
                   STTM_ACCOUNT_CLASS D
             WHERE B.CUSTOMER_NO = A.CUST_NO
               AND A.ACCOUNT_CLASS = D.ACCOUNT_CLASS
               AND A.RECORD_STAT = 'O'
                  --AND to_char(A.AC_OPEN_DATE,'YYYY')=:Year
                  --AND trim(to_char(A.AC_OPEN_DATE,'Month'))=:Month
                  --AND BRANCH_CODE ='001'
               AND A.CCY <> 'ZWD')
     group by Branch
     order by Branch) A
```

The second query is

```
(select Branch,count(*) as "No of Accounts Closed"  from(SELECT
    a.branch_code Branch,
    A.CUST_AC_NO,
    A.CCY,
    A.ACY_CURR_BALANCE,
    a.maker_id,
    a.maker_dt_stamp,
    a.checker_id,
    A.CHECKER_DT_STAMP,
    B.CUSTOMER_NAME1,
    C.ACCOUNT_CLASS,
    C.DESCRIPTION
    FROM
    STTMS_CUST_ACCOUNT A,
    STTMS_CUSTOMER B,
    STTMS_ACCOUNT_CLASS C
    WHERE
    B.CUSTOMER_NO = A.CUST_NO
    AND A.ACCOUNT_CLASS = C.ACCOUNT_CLASS
    AND A.RECORD_STAT = 'C'
    ---AND A.BRANCH_CODE ='001'- :brn
    --AND trunc(to_char(A.CHECKER_DT_STAMP,'YYYY'))=:Year
    --AND trim(to_char(A.CHECKER_DT_STAMP,'Month'))=:Month
    ORDER BY
    CUSTOMER_NAME1)group by Branch order by Branch) B
```

Comment: Could you provide of which datatype the 'Branch' is and is this column the joining condition?

Answer (score 6):

The only common column between these queries is `branch` so I'm going to assume that you want to the number of accounts closed and opened per branch.

Firstly, these queries have a lot of extraneous information; [only select what you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select). Secondly you should really be using explicit joins. They are a lot clearer, remove a obvious point where errors can occur and have been around for a few decades as the SQL standard.

The simple and quick answer to your question would be:

```
select a.*, b.*
  from query1 a
  full outer join query2 b
    on a.branch = b.branch
```

I use `full outer join` as there's no guarantee that the branch in one query exists in the other. I'm not a fan of quick and simple when I can go into detail though....

The *best* thing to do is to remove your where conditions to a `sum(case when...)` in your `select`. This enables you to only scan your tables twice rather than thrice, and then avoid doing a `full outer join` as you would have to do at the moment.

Please forgive me if I get these joins slightly wrong; I might make a mistake translating them to the explicit join syntax. I've removed some of your where conditions to the join as they should have been there.

As a little side note your worry about your query being "complex" shouldn't be a worry. Essentially, no matter how long your query you can treat it as if it were the simplest possible; just be aware of what data you think should be returned and be ready to investigate if it seems wrong.

```
select branch
     , sum(opened) as "number of accounts opened"
     , sum(closed) as "number of accounts closed"
   from ( select branch
               , sum(case when a.record_stat = 'C' then 1 
                          else 0 end) as closed
               , sum(case when a.record_stat = 'O' and a.ccy <> 'zwd' then 1 
                          else 0 end ) as opened
            from STTMS_CUST_ACCOUNT A
            join STTMS_CUSTOMER B
              on B.CUSTOMER_NO = A.CUST_NO
            join STTMS_ACCOUNT_CLASS C
              on A.ACCOUNT_CLASS = C.ACCOUNT_CLASS
              -- include where condition to use indexes (if possible)
           where a.record_stat in ('C','O')
           group by branch
              -- union would imply a distinct, which we don-t want.
           union all
          select branch
               , count(*) as opened
               , 0 as closed
            from STTM_CUST_ACCOUNT A
            join STTM_CUSTOMER  B
              on B.CUSTOMER_NO = A.CUST_NO
            join getm_facility C
              on rtrim(C.LINE_CoDe) || ltrim(to_char(C.LINE_SERIAL)) 
                 = rtrim(A.LINE_ID)
              -- moved from where as this is a join condition
             and a.record_stat = c.record_stat
            join STTM_ACCOUNT_CLASS D
              on A.ACCOUNT_CLASS = D.ACCOUNT_CLASS
            join getm_liab_cust e
              on c.liab_id = e.liab_id
             and e.customer_no = b.customer_no
             and e.customer_no = a.cust_no
             and b.liability_no = e.customer_no
              -- moved from where as this is a join condition
             and a.record_stat = e.record_stat
              -- only want one number returned so conditions in the where clause
           where A.RECORD_STAT = 'O'
             and A.CCY <> 'ZWD'
           group by branch
                 )
 group by branch
```

Sorry, I couldn't be bothered to case everything similarly.

#### Further Reading:

- [Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) - Wikipedia
- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) - Coding Horror
- [In Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) - Tech on the Net

Comment: I learned a lot from this post, especially appreciate the further reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    branches.branch_code,
    first_query."No of Accounts Opened",
    second_query."No of Accounts Closed"
from
   (select distinct branch_code from STTMS_CUST_ACCOUNT) branches
   left outer join (
       -- first query here
   ) first_query on branches.branch_code = first_query.Branch
   left outer join (
       -- second query here
   ) second_query on branches.branch_code = second_query.Branch
```

Because you haven't given a separate table for branches we have to do the `select distinct` in the first alias. If you have another table with just this information, it'd be better to use it instead.

I should add that it seems like your queries could probably be simplified (it doesn't look like you use all the fields you fetch).